# List with random numbers in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, random

I want to generate a list with random numbers in Haskell. I have to use the import System.Random library. I started doing something like that but it doesn't work. I have to create a list with N positions, and all these positions must have random numbers. Thanks!

```
System.Random library
import System.IO

x = randomRIO (1,6::Int) 

test :: IO Int
test = randomRIO (1,6::Int)
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what is not working with what you have at present.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While JP Moresmau solution is certainly preferable, you might be interested in a more transparent solution that shines some light on the `do` notation and recursive functions using `IO`:

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)

randomList :: Int -> IO([Int])
randomList 0 = return []
randomList n = do
  r  <- randomRIO (1,6)
  rs <- randomList (n-1)
  return (r:rs)
```

you should note the following:

- if `n == 0` the function will use `return` to wrap the empty list into `IO` and return this
- else inside the `do` body it will first generate a random number `r` using `randomRIO`
- next it will recursively generate a `n-1` element list of random numbers using `randomList (n-1)` and bind it to `rs`
- finally it uses `return` again to wrap `r:rs` (a `n` element list) into `IO` and return it

here is an example in **GHCi**:

```
λ> randomList 10
[2,4,4,5,2,2,2,5,6,2]

λ> randomList 10
[2,4,4,2,5,2,6,3,4,1]
```

seems random enough

#### remarks/exercise:

the function has a problem with certain values of `n` - can **you** spot it? And if so - can you change the function to be *total*?

#### having some fun

If you look closely you see that you can pull out `randomRIO (1,6) :: IO Int` there like this:

```
mList :: Int -> IO a -> IO([a])
mList 0 gen = return []
mList n gen = do
  r  <- gen
  rs <- mList(n-1) gen
  return (r:rs)
```

which of course you would have to use like this:

```
λ> mList 10 $ randomRIO (1,6)
[2,2,2,5,5,1,3,6,6,1]
```

now this has been done before (in a slightly different/better) way and you can find it as [`replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) in `Control.Monad` - with this import the function simplifies to:

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

randomList :: Int -> IO([Int])
randomList n = replicateM n $ randomRIO (1,6)
```

**fun fact** [internally](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#replicateM) this is implemented exactly as what JP answered ;)

Answer (score 16):

You need to run `randomRIO` n times. For this you can use `replicate`. This will give you a list of monadic values, that you can transform into a monadic list of values with `sequence`:

```
test :: Int -> IO [Int]
test n = sequence $ replicate n $ randomRIO (1,6::Int)
```

Comment: And then we can write it point-free
```test = ($ randomRIO (1,6::Int)) . replicateM```

Answer (score 3):

Using only one generator and infinite list

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

randomList :: (Int, Int) -> IO [Int]
randomList interval =
  newStdGen >>= return . unfoldr (Just . randomR interval)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ls <- randomList (1, 6)
  putStrLn $ show $ take 4 ls
```